# AWS RDS Postgres performance problem by MOVE ALL IN "query-cursor_1" automatic sql instruction

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, amazon-rds, database-performance

This is a FastAPI project using SQLAlchemy and an AWS RDS postgres database. The waits (AAS) on database suddenly increase above 2 (for a 2 vCPU - t4g.small instance), and when checking on Performace Insights, I see a large load on the CPU from the sql instruction **MOVE ALL IN "query-cursor_1"**, with an average latency above 200 seconds. This is happening a couple of times a day, for about five minutes each time. During these periods, database connections don't increase, and the increase in database load is not outside of the normal range.

[Waits during suddently CPU load increment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgFLU.png)

[CPU utilization and DB connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAtEN.png)

I'm not executing the **MOVE ALL IN "query-cursor_1"** instruction, and I have not been able to determine where this instruction comes from.

I'm not using cursors, so I find the execution of this instruction very strange. I do not have a clear understanding of the use of cursors, but I know that their use can lead to performance problems and table blocking. However, as I mentioned above, I am not directly executing any cursor-related instructions.

I have been changing some indexes to improve large data queries performance, but my database is relatively small with 30 tables and max half million rows in a couple of tables.

I did not find references about this query for RDS postgres databases, neither references from SQLAlchemy related to that.

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

This statement is caused by your application or by some Amazon application. It does not come from the database itself.

`MOVE ALL IN <cursor>` moves the cursor to the end of the result set. That effectively executes the complete query behind the cursor. If that query takes 200 seconds to complete, so will `MOVE ALL`.

There is one extra thing to consider: if you define a cursor, PostgreSQL will optimize statements differently. Rather than optimizing for total execution time of the complete statement, PostgreSQL will optimize for the execution time of fetching the first 10% of the rows. This is usually the right thing to do, but it is not ideal if you execute the complete query at once, like `MOVE ALL` does. Try to change the configuration parameter `cursor_tuple_fraction` from its default value of 0.1 to 1.0. Perhaps that will improve the performance for you.

Comment: I do not think this is correct. We see the same behavior, and both the user and database are `rdsadmin`, which appears to be controlled by AWS.

Comment: There is also a re:Post question about this same issue: https://repost.aws/questions/QUqZSjJ7PcS7GlZdUWvZy_KA/move-all-in-cursor-query-by-rdsadmin-blocking-complete-postgres-rds

Comment: @lukehsiao Well, then it is some Amazon application, but not the database. I'll edit my answer.